# Identifying a blank cell in Excel Office 365 using the function =IF(ISBLANK)

Tags: excel

Using excel office 365 for Mac I have entered, in cell A11, the function =if(ISBLANK(B12),0,IF(B12=0,0,B12)) to determine whether cell B12 is blank and, if so, enter 0 in cell A11, otherwise enter the content of cell B12.  Works OK except if cell b12 is emptied using the space key, in which case the result cannot be used in another cell.  Any thoughts on how to recognize a 'space bar' clearance as BLANK would be appreciated. This situation is not dealt with in the various searches I have tried and Microsoft Support has been of no help at all.

Comment: Don't use the space bar, use delete?  But other than that change this `ISBLANK(B12)` to `ISBLANK(TRIM(B12))`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Scott.  Unfortunately using 'trim' makes no difference. As before, it does return an empty-appearing cell at A11, but then accessing A11 for a calculation in another cell, C12, results in #VALUE at C12.  I don't think I can rely on all users using only delete and not the space bar.