# Using Excel, how can a cell that is cleared by the space bar be used in a formula in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula in cell A1:

```
(+B1+C1)
```

This returns a correct result to cell A1 unless a source cell (B1 or B2) has been cleared using the space bar in which case the result is `#VALUE!`.

Clearing a source cell using 'delete' provides a correct result. I have tried using

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B1),0,B4)
```

in cell B2 to test B1 with the A1 formula changed to `B2+C1`. Unfortunately this did not work.  Any suggestions to resolve this will be appreciated.  It would not be practical to expect all users to avoid using the space bar to clear a cell.

Comment: When you say "Cleared" by spacebar, i think you mean they are literally typing a space into the cell. You are saying, "What is space+c3". I think what you want is `=IFERROR(B1+C1,"")` Also, don't type spaces in your formulas! You could probably also use `Trim` and `Replace` if need be.

Comment: Did you try @Jeeped comment from your [LAST POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842501/identifying-a-blank-cell-in-excel-office-365-using-the-function-ifisblank)  Because `Sum(A1:C1)` doesn't care if it is empty, a space or has text.

Comment: Double posting? :c shame!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the space bar doesn't *clear* a cell: it inserts a string consisting of a single space. That is non-numeric data so cannot be used in a numerical calculation.

If you need to deliver a solution to a user base where "clearing with space" is endemic, then using `=IFERROR(B1*1,0)+IFERROR(C1*1, 0)` is probably the best way of dealing with this.

That clobbers all non-numeric data with a zero.